# Trying to set a name in a messagebox, depending on DateTime.now

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

To keep it short, i want to fill in name depending on the date.
im not using any database, its pure c#.

below my current code.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string vandaag = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
string bday = " has his/her birthday today";

Boolean name1 = DateTime.Now.Month == 3 && DateTime.Now.Day == 12;
Boolean name2 = DateTime.Now.Month == 6 && DateTime.Now.Day == 9;

if (name1) {MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0}. name of person 1 {1}", today, bday), "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK);}

else if (name2) {MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0}. name of person 2 {1}", today, bday), "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK);}
```

etc.

The code actually works, but like this im gonna repeat this code just for about anyone. Isnt there a way to have "name of person" filled in without having to repeat the same code over and over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do is to define a Person class like this one (expandable in future)

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime dob {get;set;}
}
```

Then you need to build a list of your Person that you want to check for their birthday

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() {Name="Steve", dob = new DateTime(1960, 3, 26)},
    new Person() {Name="John", dob = new DateTime(1961, 7, 1)},
};
```

finally your code could search if today is the Date Of Birth for any of the people list with a simple linq code

```
Person p = people.FirstOrDefault(x => x.dob.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
                                      x.dob.Day == DateTime.Today.Day);
if (p != null)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0}. Birthday of person {1}", DateTime.Today, p.Name), "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

With this approach you need only to add other Person to the list using the format above and nothing else changes. However there is a problem because you could have more than one Person with the same Date Of Birth. In this case the code that search the list becomes

```
List<Person> ppl = people.Where(x => x.dob.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && 
                                x.dob.Day == DateTime.Today.Day).ToList();
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("There are {0} people with this dob", ppl.Count));
foreach(Person p in ppl)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0}. Birthday of person {1}", DateTime.Today, p.Name), "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Comment: Despite my answer (which aimed to follow OPs code), **this** is how it should be done :-) +1

Comment: Nice one, Good luck, I just answer the question in a fast way, but you answer it charming :)

Comment: Although i can find to make it work except the last bit (i have to admit i forgot about that public class). This is more or less enough for now. im getting an error on that last p in ppl (last code fragment)

Comment: Also your answer and the one from @Jcl are correct. I think that the only important thing here is the search for an OOP approach around the data. The code clarity will benefit enormously

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (<strike>untested and written directly on Stack Overflow, handle with care</strike> *I took the time to test it and [made a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YeaS4W)... surprisingly only minor errors appeared!*):

```
static void AddBirthdayToDictionary(Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> dict, int month, int day, string name)
{
  var bdate = new DateTime(DateTime.MinValue.Year, month, day);
  List<string> val;
  if(!dict.TryGetValue(bdate, out val))
  {
    val = new List<string>();
    dict.Add(bdate, val);
  }
  val.Add(name);
}

static List<string> GetBirthdays(Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> dict, int month, int day)
{
  var bdate = new DateTime(DateTime.MinValue.Year, month, day);
  List<string> val;
  if(dict.TryGetValue(bdate, out val))
  {
    return val;
  }
  return new List<string>();
}

static void ShowBirthdays()
{
    var birthdayDictionary = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();

    // add possible birthdays    
    AddBirthdayToDictionary(birthdayDictionary, 3, 12, "Person 1");
    AddBirthdayToDictionary(birthdayDictionary, 6, 9, "Person 2");

    var today = DateTime.Today;

    // get birthdays today
    var bdayList = GetBirthdays(birthdayDictionary, today.Month, today.Day);

    if(bdayList.Any())
    {
        var count = bdayList.Count();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0} and {1} {2} celebrating {3} birthday!", today, string.Join(", ", bdayList), (count>1) ? "are":"is", (count>1) ? "their" : "its"));   
    }       
}
```

Comment: Dear @Jcl, Thanks, I just met with fiddle, something that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a list<> object so I can enumerate through the controls on a form

```
        public List<TextBox> boxes = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            boxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4};

            foreach (TextBox box in boxes)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not answering a different question?

Comment: I assumed the names are coming from TextBoxes so enumerating through the boxes would allow using a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this case using [Dictionay Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) is useful, take a look at this example:

```
public void sayHappyBirthDay(Dictionary<string, DateTime> nameBirthDay)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    foreach (var n in nameBirthDay)
    {
        if (today.Month == n.Value.Month && today.Day == n.Value.Day)
        {
            string bday = n.Key;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hello, today is {0}. name of person: {1}", today, bday), "Hello", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the excellent answer given by @Steve, I would like just to point at much simpler (no need for OOP, LINQ, Generics) implementation of essentially same functionality using 2d-array of `string[,]`:

```
// out message
string _msg = String.Empty;

// sample array of Name/Birthday
string[,] _bd = { 
                    { "Tom", "03/26/2016" }, 
                    { "Gary", "06/27/2016" }, 
                    { "Anna", "04/30/2016" } 
                };
for (int i = 0; i < _bd.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (DateTime.Today == DateTime.Parse(_bd[i, 1]))
    {
        // output message containing list of names
        _msg += _bd[i, 0] + ",";
    }
}
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_msg)) MessageBox.Show("Hello" +_msg);
```

This code snippet could be further customized/optimized by, for example, using `TryParse(), StringBuilder`, etc.